# X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Tags: opengl, ssh, x11, nvidia, tegra

I'm trying to compile and run this c++ code

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void displayMe(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello world :D");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayMe);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

which is a "opengl's hello world" I found online.
I'm doing this to test my university's NVIDIA Tegra X1, the TX1 development kit is always on and connected to the university's network.
I'm connecting to the TX1 via ssh (using the -X flag). Compiling went fine, but when I try to run the program, this error appears:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

I haven't found anything online and I have no idea what is going on.

PS: I'm connecting first to my university's network via ssh (using -X) and then I do another ssh to connect to the TX1.

Comment: What command did you use to compile?

Comment: @EliSadoff g++ main.cpp -o lookAtThis -lglut

Comment: When you do X-over-SSH then OpenGL commands are serialized into the X11 transport to be processed by the display server and hardware on the machine you're logging in from. So you're not even using the Tegra for OpenGL.

Comment: @datenwolf really? I didn't realize that. So I can't test the graphic output of the TX1 via ssh?

Comment: @ViniciusMilaniR.Freitas: Not via X11 tunneling. X11 is effectively just transmitting the drawing commands (as remote procedure calls) to the X11 server on the machine with the display, and the commands are executed there. What you have to do is start an X11 server on the remote machine (does that even work with Tegra?) and use some remote framebuffer (VNC or such) to transmit the result.

Comment: @datenwolf interesting, thanks for the reply!

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/893922/ubuntu-16-04-x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-of-range

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was getting errors like this:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
name of display: :99
```

On a remote machine, with nvidia graphics card.
Solved the problem by installing the NVIDIA driver from .run file, with the option --no-opengl-files (Inspired from here: https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07)

Hope this helps!

Comment: btw, this specific error (GLX:24 X_GLXCreateNewContext) error will happens when your video driver is updated for a running X server, restart X to resolve it

Comment: @ThorSummoner I had this same issue, and I *did* just update my Nvidia drivers. Restarting X did fix it as you suggested. So, thank you.

Comment: @ThorSummoner Thank you so much, just ran into this and your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: For future readers, I fixed my problem by just running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` followed by `sudo reboot`.

Comment: Mircea, did you find anything posted useful?
It is useful if you provide feedback.

Answer (score 21):

I was getting this same error when running `glxgears` (to check that OpenGL was running properly). I then realized that my nvidia-drivers were borked:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

I just needed to restart my computer. `nvidia-smi` and `glxgears` worked after reboot.

**In summary**: try restarting your computer

Comment: I think this is the problem. I copy my file to another machine and the problem dissapeared

Comment: Incredible how the most simple solution provides a fix for any problems. Thanks

Comment: solves my problem too. this should be accepted as answer

Comment: Is there a mechanism to determine whether a restart is needed? When I switch into a Terminal session using Alt+F-something, then the login-screen tells that a reboot is required. However in the graphical session, I don't see anything obvious telling me to reboot, or at least I don't see it.

Comment: @DohnJoe first off, what OS are you on and do you have an nvidia graphics card?

Comment: It's an Ubuntu-22.04 machine with an Nvidia card. I guess I should research this more and open a new, separate question.

Comment: @DohnJoe what's the output of `nvidia-smi`? if it's a summary of your nvidia driver + graphics cards then this isn't the issue your having. If it's "failed to initialize NVML: ..." then this is what's going on

Comment: It's driver+graphics.

Comment: gotcha, then something else is the issue

Answer (score 9):

Adding my user to the `video` group and rebooting solved the problem for me ([source](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1102186-start-0.html)). `glxgears` now also works.
Still have to check if there are other related issues not resolved.